# While writing a dict to a data frame and then to excel. The list values in dict are coming in one row

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, list, dataframe

```
        listDataFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
            Data)
        listDataFrame.to_excel(
            fullpath, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=TRUE)
```

The result for the above is coming as below. But I want the the values of dict which are of list type to be in next rows instead of same row
[1 rows x 17 columns]

I want to dataframe to explore into multiple rows but dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the orientation of [**`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)
to `"index"` then use [**`pandas.DataFrame.transpose`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html).

```
listDataFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Data, orient="index").T

listDataFrame.to_excel(fullpath, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=True)
```